# Get the sum of maximum subarray in a given input array of elements using modulus

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am trying to solve a subarray problem using BruteForce technique with O(n^2) complexity. The code works for small data sets but for some reason it doesn't go right for large numbers. What am I doing wrong with the logic. Can someone help me with this.

**Question explanation :-**

[image]

[image]

Sample Input :-

```
1
50 1804289384
846930887 1681692778 1714636916 1957747794 424238336 719885387 1649760493 596516650 1189641422 1025202363 1350490028 783368691 1102520060 2044897764 1967513927 1365180541 1540383427 304089173 1303455737 35005212 521595369 294702568 1726956430 336465783 861021531 278722863 233665124 2145174068 468703136 1101513930 1801979803 1315634023 635723059 1369133070 1125898168 1059961394 2089018457 628175012 1656478043 1131176230 1653377374 859484422 1914544920 608413785 756898538 1734575199 1973594325 149798316 2038664371 1129566414
```

Expected Output :-

```
1802192837
```

Actual output ( what I am getting ) :-

```
1802467240
```

**Code :-**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static long maximumSum(long[] a, long m) {

        long sum = 0;  
        long val = 0;

        for ( int i=0;i<a.length;i++ ) {                                     
             for( int j=i;j<a.length;j++ ) {
                 val = val + a[i];
                 if( val%m > sum )
                 sum = val%m;                 
             }                
            val = 0;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            long m = in.nextLong();
            long[] a = new long[n];
            for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
                a[a_i] = in.nextLong();
            }
            long result = maximumSum(a, m);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**Compilation successful but getting a run time exception as below :-**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:29)
```

Comment: You have assumed we understand what you mean by _"sum of maximum subarray"_.  Please explain the problem you're trying to solve.  Also, how can your program both produce an answer and terminate with an exception?

Comment: added screenshot for explanation.. sorry was few seconds late...

Comment: Given the problem statement, none of your answers look correct. The largest possible answer is 6 based on modulo 7.  Also you haven't explained what the first 2 input lines are for.  Please step back and reframe the question assuming nobody here is in the same course or has access to any of materials.

Comment: Yes... the code works fine for the sample data provided in screen-shots.. I am testing the code for larger data set... Even though its brute force I think that my algorithm should work...

Comment: What is the meaning of the first two lines of input? Where does the 7 (modulo) come from?

Comment: m is passed as an input parameter to the method maximumSum. both array and modulo are passed as input parameters to this method.

Comment: I think I can answer my own question. The first line (`1`) contains the repetitions of this test (i.e. the total number of arrays in the input). The second line (`5 7`) has two numbers. The first number (5) is the size of the array and the second number is the modulo. The third line are the 5 elements of the array. In your large-numbers test, the first line is 10000 but you don't have 10000 arrays following it. You only have 1. That's why you get an exception.

Comment: The exception is caused by the first line of input. You told it there would be 10,000 input cases but only provided 1 input array.  As to the calculation error, how do you KNOW the correct answer? Did you manually work out the value? How long did that take you?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my input @DodgyCodeException. I just changed it. But still the output doesnt match... Whats wrong with my algo?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am working on this problem in hackerrank and I am provided with expected output...

Comment: The structure of your nested loops is totally wrong.  Your sliding window is anchored at the right `for( int j=i;j<a.length;j++ )`, so it never considers subarrays that don't end at the last element.

Comment: Why do you think its wrong? For every ith iteration I am checking n elements... n,n-1,n-2,n-3.....3,2,1 which would cover all the edge cases. What is still wrong? Can you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: @JimGarrison that's ok, if val%m for a subarray ending less than a.length is greater than one ending at a.length, it will not affect `sum` (the maximum).

Comment: @Teja your code looks correct to me (though I haven't studied it in great detail). Why not print out the indexes of the subarray that gives you the maximum and then do the sum by hand?

Comment: By the way, I think your variable names are confusing. I would use the name `currentSum` instead of `val`, and `maximumSum` instead of `sum`.

Comment: OK, you have a trivial typo.  See if you can find it.

Comment: Oops... I just typed an answer and then saw your comment @JimGarrison. I then quickly deleted my answer. Your comment is a much better idea!

Comment: Thank you guys!! Now the code is working fine. But my code is timing out for large data sets... How can i optimize this logic or should I use a different data structure totally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think J loop is problem you are filling entire sub array with same element

```
 for ( int i=0;i<a.length;i++ ) {                                     
             for( int j=i;j<a.length;j++ ) {
                 val = val + **a[i]**;
                 if( val%m > sum )
                 sum = val%m;                 
             }                
            val = 0;
        }

Change 
val = val + a[i];
to 
val = val + a[J];
```

Comment: Thanks Praful... you made it right... but for large data sets my code is timing out.... :(

Comment: @Teja what is large data set ? can you be more specific with data u r using and problem u r getting ?